# Apache proxy/rewrite with basic auth

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, proxy, mod-proxy

I'm trying to configure and apache server to act as a proxy and having some problems.

What i want is to be able to make a request from my home computer to apache running on a server and have apache forward this request on to a final destination.

The request must look as if it's originated from the server and it must carry the basic authentication header that's passed from my home computer to the apache server.

I've tried using mod_proxy and simply:

```
ServerName proxy.server.com

ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia Block
RewriteEngine on

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    SetEnv proxy-chain-auth
    SetEnv proxy-sendcl
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / http://api.finaldestination.com/v1/
ProxyPassReverse / http://api.finaldestination.com/v1/
```

And this is fine except the final destination server is redirecting me (302 responses) so i'm assuming it's picking up the fact that the request url is proxy.server.com instead of api.finaldestination.com.

I also tried a RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule ^something/(.*)$ http://api.finaldestination.com/v1/something/$1 [P]
```

but now the basic authentication header doesn't get passed and i get a 404 from api.finaldestination.com

i'm clearly missing something obvious here - can anyone help?

i'm using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Did you uncommented the load modules part for proxy mod line in apache.conf or httpd.conf file

Comment: You need to load the module at start & then in virtual host block you need to put correct entries .

Comment: I used a2enmod proxy and a2enmod rewrite - my httpd.conf is just a VirtualHost block with the above in it.

Comment: Which os platform you are using ??

Comment: i'm using ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can try  [Since you have ubuntu 12.04 steps are for this OS]

Run the following command to install build-essential package:

```
aptitude install -y build-essential
```

Then take care of other modules

```
aptitude install -y libapache2-mod-proxy-html libxml2-dev
```

Activate the modules

```
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
a2enmod proxy_ajp
a2enmod rewrite
a2enmod deflate
a2enmod headers
a2enmod proxy_balancer
a2enmod proxy_connect
a2enmod proxy_html
```

Now edit the file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

use gedit or vi editor to edit the file

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://api.finaldestination.com/v1/
ProxyPassReverse / http://api.finaldestination.com/v1/

    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Make sure everything else remains default which was from start.

Now everything coming to Proxy Server will be passed to "http://api.finaldestination.com/v1/" which is your intention.

Now in 302 Redirection you need to PUT Rewrite ON on "http://api.finaldestination.com/v1/" webserver
& everything else you can manage on .htaccess file

Once you are Through with this then you can for for Proxy authentication part 
via

```
<Location />
    AuthType Basic
    ...
</Location>
```

Authentication can differ according to Authentication you plan to use

You can refer Examples  [**Here**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Apache+frontend+for+security)

In some cases for me I used below stuff

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domainname.com

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyErrorOverride On
    ProxyPass   /   http://target-url/
    ProxyPassReverse   /   http://target-url/

    <Location />
        AuthType basic
        AuthBasicAuthoritative Off
        SetEnv proxy-chain-auth On
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: thanks for this - this works... up to a point. it seems the finaldestination is seeing that the ORIGINAL request is originating in a country that it's blocking. To be clear the apache proxy can make a successful request (via curl) but when i send a request from my machine THROUGH the proxy i'm blocked and the response says INVALID_COUNTRY. So the next question is, how can i stop any hint of the original request getting through to finaldestination?